# What is a word for a big, insurmountable problem?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe unemployment in the first sentence of an economics essay about South Africa. The sentence I'm thinking of is, "Unemployment is a ... problem in South Africa,... "

I'm trying to think of a word to put in the first ellipsis, and it should have the connotation of the following words: widespread, malignant, intractable, pernicious, enduring, problematic, big, serious,... you get the idea. Can you think of the word I'm trying to find?

The sentence can be modified from the one I suggested; my aim is to have a powerful opening sentence.

Comment: Does it have to be an adjective - IOW precede "problem" - or can it be a noun, taking the place of "problem"?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an adjective if the sentence is still powerful.

Comment: It is possible that the word I'm looking for is "intractable" and that I'm just asking this question because I'm trying to brainstorm with others and make sure that's what I want.

Comment: Or maybe "significant".

Comment: Some of your examples suggest a problem that's been around for a long time (enduring),  and has proven difficult to rectify (intractable), or pervasive (widespread).  Which aspect(s) are you trying to deal with?

Comment: I'm just looking for a powerful opening sentence. I like the sentence, "Unemployment is a significant and intractable problem in South Africa, which calls for attention on possible solutions." @mike65535 the essay looks at the effect of government grants on work-seeking behaviour.

Comment: 'It doesn't have to be an adjective if the sentence is still powerful.' shouldn't be in a comment: you need to edit the question. This makes a large difference.

Comment: A snafu is one word that comes to mind.  If you want a powerful opening sentence, you need to use an ***action verb*** and not "is". Unemployment plagues South Africa. Unemployment gnaws away at the South Africa. Just example.

Comment: @ahorn I like your idea of "intractable" as I think really you are after the persistency and the lack of progress in elimination more than the impossibility or absolute size you are after (importance vs size).  What I like about 'intractable' is that oddly enough, it suggests a tiny bit of optimism - if only a way of getting traction could be found - it calls for a hope for cause of action. However, if the paper has broader audiences, intractable is too elevated for plain english goals.  "seemingly unconquerable" might be dramatic(adversary at war with)with edge of hope from seemingly

Comment: I think you're too hung up on one adjective. Just write a really good overall essay that _shows_ how unemployment is an intractable, persistent problem.

Comment: I hesitate to put this in an answer because it's already in your title, but what's wrong with "insurmountable"?

Comment: If the problem is intractable and insurmountable, why would a reader want to continue with your essay?  Thus, I like "conundrum" (one of the following answers).  Hard to figure out, but keep reading!

Comment: What aspect of unemployment is the paper talking about?

Comment: try an arch-important problem

Comment: brexit seems to fit

Comment: @Racheet I think it's because I want to be optimistic.

Comment: @BenAveling the effect of government grants on labour force participation.

Comment: I see that there were two close votes, so I'm sorry that this question was a bit fuzzy. But I like how we've brainstormed some good words! I didn't expect there to be so many views.

Comment: If you'll take a noun, there's *conundrum*

Comment: My understanding is that *intractable* means that technically it could probably be solved except the scale of the problem is just too large for there to be a straightforward solution. Not knowing a lot about unemployment in Africa, I can't be certain, but just judging by the size of the continent and vast array of cultures and social issues, *intractable* seems like a very good word for any problem that plagues the entire continent.

Comment: @ahorn Intentional effects, or incidental effects?

Comment: @BenAveling well, unemployment is incidental.

Comment: @yahorn And you're going to argue that with more care, there could be less unemployment? If so, then maybe the word you want to use is "avoidable". You'll need to explain (later) that it isn't completely avoidable - but that it doesn't need to be as bad as it is, if only <something something something> is done differently. Whatever you are going to be talking about later, that is the idea you want to put into your readers head now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77478/discussion-on-question-by-ahorn-what-is-a-word-for-a-big-insurmountable-problem).

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. Specifically, this question seems to be more of a writing advice request, especially in light of the comment trail. Because of the inherent subjectivity of writing advice requests, they are a poor fit for the SE model.

Comment: @MetaEd sorry. I should probably read more instead of hoping for the perfect word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's "pervasive"

> (especially of an unwelcome influence or physical effect) spreading widely throughout an area or a group of people.

Synonyms:   prevalent, pervading, permeating, extensive, ubiquitous, omnipresent, universal, rife, widespread, general

Or "perennial", to focus on the permanent nature.

You could go with some anthropomorphism, and say "Unemployment has been an implacable foe of South Africa".

Comment: Pervasive does *not* mean insurmountable, though the reason a problem is insurmountable might be due to it being pervasive.

Answer (score 16):

English is above all a verbalizing language (as opposed to, say, French, which is a nominalizing language). So, use an active verb aka action verb. In other words, we have strong verbs and they have strong nouns. This is a generalization that happens to be true. My opinion is: forget the verb to be and adjectives. Go for a good verb. These are some I thought of. I am sure others can come up with a plethora of other ones.

- Unemployment gnaws away at South Africa.
- Unemployment plagues South Africa.
- Unemployment undermines South African society.
- Unemployment burdens South Africa.
- Unemployment throttles South Africa.

Here's a sample:

Read a good weather forecast and you’ll find the weather patterns described with such active verbs as “hammered,” “trounced,” “sliced,” and “eased.” Read a good sportscast and you’ll find gleeful discussions of how a losing team was “throttled,” “bashed,” “whipped,” or “humiliated.”

[active verbs](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/writingpersonalstatementsonline/p3_p5.html)

Comment: "Unemployment throttles South Africa" is very powerful!

Comment: *is running rampant*

Comment: is running rampant is not a strong action verb.

Answer (score 7):

I think you may describe South Africa unemployment as a ***[plague](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plague):***

> If you describe something as a plague, you mean that it causes a great deal of trouble or harm.
>
> - Inflation will remain a recurrent plague.
> - Tim seems to have escaped the cynicism which is the absolute plague of our generation.

(Collins Dictionary)

Usage example from the [Journal of Business and Management](https://books.google.it/books?id=LKuMAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20plague%20of%20unemployment%22&dq=%22the%20plague%20of%20unemployment%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFiZ6x2_3aAhUIPFAKHSdyB3AQ6AEIKjAB) 2003

> ***The mostly affected by the plague of unemployment*** in Nigeria today are young school leavers, particularly graduates from tertiary institutions, and the bulk of people retrenched from work (Ofido, 1999:33). The unemployment situation, which ...

Other usage examples of “*plague of unemployment*” can be found here in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plague%20of%20unemployment&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplague%20of%20unemployment%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest **Monumental**

Given the context, you want a word to describe a problem that is big, difficult to break down and dominates the problemscape.

In the context of your phrase, Monumental would be an entirely appropriate choice I think.

A variation on this might be **Monolithic, Dominating/Dominant** or perhaps **Pervasive** to emphasise that it's a widespread problem at many levels of society.

Comment: I like [pervasive](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/445714/96579)

Answer (score 5):

Unemployment is a *crippling* problem in South Africa…

Unemployment *cripples* all subsequent endeavors in South Africa…

Answer (score 4):

> Unemployment is the ***scourge*** of the South African economy...

ODO:

> **[scourge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/scourge)**
>   *NOUN*
>   A person or thing that causes great trouble or suffering.
>
> ‘the scourge of mass unemployment’
>
> ‘Unemployment, long the scourge of the Irish economy, remains very
>   low, at around 4.5%, despite the recent slowdown in economic growth.’

Answer (score 4):

Unemployment is **an *endemic*** problem in South Africa,...

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endemic)

> 1b : characteristic of or prevalent in a particular field, area, or environment ·problems endemic to translation
>    ·the self-indulgence endemic in the film industry

I think this would be a good word choice as it evokes the idea of a more localized problem rather than the term *epidemic* which has connotations of a more widespread problem. You are focusing on South Africa in particular rather than on unemployment in general so use a word that focuses it.

Additionally, borrowing from it's more common use in reference to disease helps mark it as something that requires an active treatment and will not correct itself on its own.

You could also combine it with ***systemic*** for a more powerful sentence.

> **Endemic** unemployement is a **systemic** problem in South Africa

[Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systemic)

> **systemic:** of, relating to, or common to a system

Comment: Endemic does not at all have this meaning. [Guinea worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracunculiasis) is endemic to many areas but far from insurmountable; we've almost eradicated it through education and water filters (no medications!)

Comment: @curiousdannii I feel like we are saying the same thing. You cite the Guinea worm as an example of an endemic problem. I agree that it is endemic rather than an epidemic. It has gotten to this point through action (as you accurately point out: education and water treatment) rather than being left untreated. Without these efforts, the Guinea worm would still be a much larger health problem.

Comment: Endemic just means that it's "native" rather than introduced. It in no ways means an insurmountable problem. Guinea worm is endemic where it exists for as long as it exists. It's prevalence is tangential to its endemic nature.

Comment: Are you referencing "insurmountable" because it's in the OP's title? The actual question and comments indicated to me that they weren't literally looking for a word that meant that. If they were, pretty much none of the answers, including the accepted one (pervasive), mean insurmountable. The closest is 'intractable' which was already mentioned by OP in the question comments.

Comment: @PC Indeed, it's not a great question, but the title and body are compatible. Some of the other answers are bad too.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest **chronic**.

adjective [usually ADJECTIVE noun]
A chronic situation or problem is very severe and unpleasant.
One cause of the artist's suicide seems to have been chronic poverty.
There is a chronic shortage of patrol cars in this police district.

source:Collins Dictionary,

Comment: I cannot fathom why Collins lists that as a definition, because that really isn't what chronic means. I guess it's a common misuse of the word and maybe they decided to capture that.
Chronic refers to something occurring repeatedly or for a long time (hence "chron-" as in "chronological", having to do with time).
Please don't use "chronic" to mean bad.

Comment: @Dancrumb it's actually a proper definition, it's also listed by [Cambridge Dictionary (_very bad_)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chronic) and  [ODO (_Of a very poor quality_)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chronic). Both list it as British English by the way.

Comment: Both of those definitions are informal; certainly British slang and definitely not appropriate for an essay.

Comment: As a slang term, chronic can also mean marijuana.

Comment: @Dancrumb if it's slang it's also American. I've used chronic in exactly this way before and no one has ever blinked an eye

Comment: This is my second best answer - chronic is a good adjective for later on in the essay, but maybe not the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

How about 'intractable' ? 
Unusual, dramatic, determinant. 
Meaning includes hard to control or deal with.
"intractable economic problems"
synonyms:   unmanageable, uncontrollable, ungovernable, out of control, out of hand, impossible to cope with;

Comment: OP has suggested 'intractable'.

Answer (score 3):

> Unemployment is a (serious) ***malady*** in South Africa

Collins:

> **[malady](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malady)**
>   2. *countable noun*
>   In written English, people sometimes use *maladies* to refer to serious problems in a society or situation.
>   When apartheid is over the maladies will linger on.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Examples on the web:

> [Google search for "unemployment is a malady"](https://www.google.com/search?q="unemployment+is+a+malady")
>   [Google search for "unemployment is a serious malady"](https://www.google.com/search?q="unemployment+is+a+serious+malady")

Answer (score 3):

**Unemployment strangles South Africa**!

> **[Strangle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strangle)** :(verb) (Cambridge Dictionary)
>
> to stop something from developing.
>
> ***There is a great deal of fear that the new restrictions might strangle the country's economy.***

Comment: Isn't that a bit too personified?

Comment: @ahorn, Yes, even so, it adds to the acceptance of the word. After all, unemployment strangles the country-men!

Answer (score 2):

**Epidemic**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epidemic):

> a particular problem that seriously affects many people at the same time:

Example by Cambridge Dictionary:

> a crime/**unemployment epidemic**

Attribution: "Epidemic Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Epidemic Definition in the Cambridge English Dictionary. Accessed May 11, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epidemic.

#### Real-world examples

> [Financial Times column](https://www.ft.com/content/13fdad22-9845-11e0-ae45-00144feab49a), titled: **Causes of unemployment epidemic lie within borders**
>
> [Huffignton Post blog](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/weekly-audit-the-unemploy_b_352749.html), titled: **Weekly Audit: The Unemployment Epidemic**
>
> Publication by [Levy Economics Institute of Bard College](http://www.levyinstitute.org/publications/unemployment-the-silent-epidemic), titled: **Unemployment: The Silent Epidemic**
>
> [Column by US senator Bernie Sanders at Mic.com](https://mic.com/articles/183121/bernie-sanders-youth-jobs-bill-unemployment#.EPzIM0k0Y), titled: **Youth unemployment is epidemic in America. It’s time to give our young people a chance to succeed.**

Answer (score 2):

You could, very easily, use the word [conundrum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conundrum) to fit your needs.

> an intricate and difficult problem
>
> ```
> He is faced with the conundrum of trying to find a job without having experience.
> ```

Usage in your sentence would be as follows:

> Unemployment is a conundrum in South Africa,...

I might even re-write the sentence as such:

> Unemployment in South Africa is quite the conundrum...

Comment: When I hear conundrum I think of a challenging question or decision, but not necessarily a widespread problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Predicament**.  The fact that you cannot solve it on your own is what makes it a predicament, rather than just a problem.

However, if it's a problem that cannot be solved *in the normal ways*, and you are about to solve it via unconventional methods, then it's a **[Gordian knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot)**.

Comment: In typical use today, "predicament" has a somewhat trivializing connotation. "We only have forks for our soup. Well isn't that a predicament!" I would strongly caution against using this word unless you _intend_ to make light of the situation.

Comment: @mattdm but what you are describing is actually **sarcasm** or **irony**.  It could apply to any word, and you seem to be saying "predicament" is a word preferred in sarcastic use.  Okay, but I would argue it's preferred **because it's a great word**.  I'm not so sure that dilutes its value in straight use.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I mean, there is some amount of that, but in the US at least it is rarely used in a very serious way. Look at what Merriam-Webster offers as synonyms: words like *pickle, jam, sticky wicket, kettle of fish*.

Comment: I agree that predicament will be seen as understatement.

Comment: Don't be mad - you *literally* told me to [fact-check](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/predicament) you! Three of your terms **were cherry-picked** from the *tail* of a much longer list of serious terms. [Other synonym pages](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=predicament+synonym) concur.  I also googled "predicament" and random words: oil, climate, bee, harold, kumar, unserious... Outside of a few ringers like "cat", the usage is serious. I'll graciously assume you fell into the fallacy of considering only evidence you agree with.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest word possible would be the adjective [**huge**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/huge) as it's also used to convey the idea of being *of great importance or seriousness*:

> Unemployment is a **huge** problem in South Africa...

Answer (score 1):

As is:

> Your example: Unemployment is a ... problem in South Africa.
>
> Suggested:   The big **imbroglio** in South Africa: unemployment!

[imbroglio - TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/imbroglio)

A difficult or intricate situation; an entanglement. A confused
or complicated disagreement. A confused or perplexing **political** or interpersonal situation.
An unwanted, difficult, and confusing *situation*, full of trouble and problems

As in:

> A society that keeps on barking at the industry and keeps
> reaping benefits out of a bad education system also finds it
> convenient to blame the Govt. for the **imbroglio called
> unemployment**.  [lindedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/unraveling-unemployment-woes-hr-pandit)
>
> “The **Unemployment Imbroglio**,” in “The Legislative Ledger,” LCS,
> 2/4/70. SF2,news cols. 15. AWB, WB, 2/70; WSLC, “Labor Looks at the
> 41st Session of the ...  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=JsAqqiQtVCoC&lpg=PT448&ots=ZOMned52SX&dq=%22unemployment%20imbroglio%22&pg=PT448#v=onepage&q=%22unemployment%20imbroglio%22&f=false)

Comment: My understanding of "imbroglio" is that it's situation of tension between people, not a problem involving impersonal forces.

Comment: @Acccumulation see link: a confused or perplexing political or interpersonal situation

Comment: I really don't think imbroglio characterizes unemployment.  The orange man is currently experiencing more than one imbroglio.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. An interpersonal situation. Unemployment is not an interpersonal situation, except at the most reductionist.

Comment: @Lambie  i added a citation.  Used frequently with such in the states.

Comment: Yes, fine.  I would not use it in the first sentence as given by the OP.

Comment: Lambie's right, this connotes a complicated celebrity feud or political infighting, not a crushing social problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the short question which might bring people here or serve as a dupe target, I'd suggest **wicked**, even though other answers' options might be a better fit for the very specific problem noted in the question details.

Wicked problems are big and insurmountable, and **so is even trying to specifically define the problem and its boundaries.**  Other [specific characteristics of "wicked problems,"](http://www.leanessays.com/2002/01/wicked-problems.html) for precise use of the term (better not to overuse it!), can be found in a famous [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307144800/http://www.uctc.net/mwebber/Rittel+Webber+Dilemmas+General_Theory_of_Planning.pdf):

> Rittel, Horst W. J., and Melvin M. Webber. “Dilemmas in a General Theory of Planning.” *Policy Sciences 4* (1973): 155–69.

Today, climate change is often given as the canonical example of a wicked problem.

Comment: Do you think this sense of 'wicked' is one that is limited to academia? I have seen this sense of the word when studying public policy & administration.

Comment: @ahorn I think it started with people studying public policy & administration, with this sense.  Note the venue and title of the paper.